# Splitting a record into multiple records based on character length

Tags: python, pyspark

I have to split records in a dataframe into multiple records based on character lengths.
**UPDATE**:

The dataframe will have the key in a separate column. The `value` column should be split every 5 characters as above. The key should repeat with every new row generated. Also, a sequence number is required for every 5 character chunk that is split into a new record.

```
key  | value
ABC1 | 2345DEFMN45671
XYZ  | 56712MNPQR2347762344
DEF  | 38912JKLTR
```

Expected output:

```
Key | seq | value
ABC | 1   | 12345
ABC | 2   | DEFMN
ABC | 3   | 45671 
XYZ | 1   | 56712
XYZ | 2   | MNPQR
XYZ | 3   | 23477
XYZ | 4   | 62344
DEF | 1   | 38912
DEF | 2   | JKLTR
```

As shown above, there is a new sequence no column added to the dataframe. Please note that the seq no should exactly pertain to the order in which the split string occurs in the source.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the native Pyspark approach.

```
df = (df.select('key', F.split(F.regexp_replace('value', r'([0-9A-Z]{5})(?!$)', '$1,'), ',').alias('value'))
      .select('key', 'value', F.sequence(F.lit(1), F.size('value')).alias('seq'))
      .select('key', F.explode(F.arrays_zip('value', 'seq')).alias('v'))
      .select('key', 'v.seq', 'v.value'))
```

Here is the steps:

1. Use `split` and `regexp_replace` to split the `value` in fixed length of 5.
2. Make a sequence array from 1 to the size of the splitted array using `sequence`. At this point, the dataframe should look like

```
+---+----------------------------+------------+
|key|value                       |seq         |
+---+----------------------------+------------+
|ABC|[12345, DEFMN, 45671]       |[1, 2, 3]   |
|XYZ|[56712, MNPQR, 23477, 62344]|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|DEF|[38912, JKLTR]              |[1, 2]      |
+---+----------------------------+------------+
```

3. Finally, use `arrays_zip` and `explode`, explode the value&seq pair.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a module that will split the records as you wish. It takes the first three characters as the key and appends 5.
EDIT: I added the seq column:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'records': [
        "ABC12345DEFMN45671",
        "XYZ56712MNPQR2347762344",
        "DEF38912JKLTR"
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def split_record(record):
    key = record[:3] 
    rest = record[3:]

    new_records_with_seq = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(rest), 5):
        seq = (i // 5) + 1  # calculate seq
        value = rest[i:i+5]
        new_records_with_seq.append((key, seq, value))
    
    return new_records_with_seq

expanded_records = df['records'].apply(split_record).explode().tolist()

new_df = pd.DataFrame(expanded_records, columns=["key", "seq", "value"])

print(new_df)
```

[image]

EDIT:
The above works in Pandas, here is the method for Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SplitRecords").getOrCreate()

data = [("ABC12345DEFMN45671",), ("XYZ56712MNPQR2347762344",), ("DEF38912JKLTR",)]
schema = StructType([StructField("records", StringType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

def split_record(record):
    key = record[:3]
    rest = record[3:]
    return [(key, i + 1, rest[i*5:(i+1)*5]) for i in range((len(rest) + 4) // 5)]

split_record_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType(), False),
    StructField("seq", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("value", StringType(), False)
]))

split_record_udf = udf(split_record, split_record_schema)

df_with_splits = df.withColumn("splits", explode(split_record_udf("records")))

final_df = df_with_splits.select(
    "splits.key",
    "splits.seq",
    "splits.value"
)

final_df.show(truncate=False, vertical=False)
```

This creates the following dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. There has been a slight modification to the requirement. Could you please also help with that.-- A sequence number column is required for each new record created and the key will be in a separate column in the dataframe. Please scroll down the question to get the updated requirements. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matthew Does that suffice? I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Is this achievable with PySpark dataframes ?

Comment: @Matthew ah, yeah, it’ll be a bit different since pyspark handles dataframes across distributed clusters and has different syntax. Don’t quite have time right now but will update my answer later

Comment: your latest solution doesn't use the new changed input format shown in the question. Please see the UPDATE section of my question. The input now has been split into 2 columns key and value. We have to take that into consideration. Also, it would be great if you can give the solution in PySpark. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, the input data is already in a PySpark dataframe with 2 columns - key & value. We have to split the value column, and put the seq no and key column should just repeat.

Comment: @Matthew isn’t that what I did? If not, please clarify why the output I’m showing at the bottom of my answer isn’t right

Comment: can you please help in writing this in Pyspark please.

Comment: @Matthew I updated my answer with Pyspark. If my answer is good Id appreciate an "accept". Cheers